# How to initialize the dynamic array of chars with a string literal in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, dynamic-arrays, syntactic-sugar

I want to do the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer = new char[ /* ... */ ] { "/tmp/file-XXXXXX" };
```

Obviously, it doesn't work because I haven't specified the size of a new array. What is an appropriate way to achieve my goal without counting symbols in a string literal?

Usage of `std::array` is also welcome.

**Update #1:** even if I put the size of array, it won't work either.

**Update #2:** it's vital to have a *non-const* access to the array as a simple `char*` pointer.

Comment: A dynamic arrays of chars, so you mean a `string` - which incidentally offers the right constructor too. Well `sizeof("/tmp/lala")` will work for the size if it's a constant (that includes the `\0` too though so be careful).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution based on `std::array`:

```
std::array<char, sizeof("/tmp/file-XXXXXX")> arr{ "/tmp/file-XXXXXX" };
```

You can reduce the boilerplate using a macro:

```
#define DECLARE_LITERAL_ARRAY(name, str) std::array<char, sizeof(str)> name{ str }
DECLARE_LITERAL_ARRAY(arr, "/tmp/file-XXXXXX");
```

The `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time, so there is no runtime scanning of the literal string to find its length. The resulting array is null-terminated, which you probably want anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since you requested a dynamic array and not wanting to count the length, that rules out `std::array<char,N>`. What you're asking for is really just `std::string` - it's dynamic (if need be), and initializes just fine from a `char*` without counting the length. Internally, it stores the string in a flat array, so you can use it as such, via the `c_str()` call.

Comment: I don't want `string` since the array will go as **non-const** `char*` to `mkstemp()`

Comment: Exactly right, but a small example of initializing a `string` object with a literal string, and then calling `c_str` in order to retrieve the `char` array would make this answer even better.

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify the whole problem! Since `mkstemp()` modifies its argument, you're right that we need non-const memory. Two options: `const_cast<char*>(str.c_str())` ... which is awful, but it's your string and `mkstemp()` doesn't change the length, so it might be ok. Or you will need to count chars and use the `std::array`. Or you can do: `char* buf = new char[strlen(template)]; copy(template.begin(),template.end(),buf.begin());`

Comment: @JHUmphrey Casting const away is *not* an option. It's not just awful but simply illegal (exhibits undefined behavior) as far as I can see.

Comment: @Voo: It may be awful but it's only illegal if `str.c_str() != &str[0]`, otherwise the original storage is guaranteed to be mutable and hence `const` can be legally cast away.

Comment: @Mehrdad Hum, that's actually guaranteed by the standard? (i.e. that `str.c_str() == &str[0]`?) Didn't think it was although I guess it's probably true for most implementations.

Comment: @Voo: I'm not sure? All I was saying was that merely casting away constness is not *necessarily* illegal by itself; I never said it's necessarily always legal either. i.e. it depends on run-time behavior.

Comment: @Mehrdad Fair point. And I actually looked into the standard: It does require continuous memory for the string itself, so there's really no sane reason (I can think of) where an implementer wouldn't go for the obvious implementation I can think of. So yeah pretty unlikely to break.

Comment: @Voo: It can be that there are two copies of the string, and different pointers are returned for the const version for special cases as an optimization of some sort. I don't know of any implementation that does this, but I don't think I'd go so far as to consider such an implementation unreasonable. (Note that this is different from a non-contiguous implementation, which I *would* find unreasonable.)

Comment: @Mehrdad A non-contigous implementation could make some operations much more efficient though, so for some situations I could see the use in that (you're probably better off using a special library then, but still). But keeping two copies of the same string in memory? Yeah don't see what optimizations that'd allow.

Comment: @Mehrdad [string.accessors]/p3 explicitly bans altering the chars pointed to by `c_str()` or `data()`: "*Requires:* The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array."

Comment: That's about as definitive as it gets. I think we should avoid this method, given how strict the standard is on it.

Comment: @T.C., JHumphrey: Since it's totally legal to modify the target through the non-const pointer, when the two pointers compare equal, that remark about the const pointer is completely moot because the array can be modified regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you're not using `std::string`; you can do `str.empty() ? NULL : &str[0]` to get a non-const pointer, so the constness of `str.c_str()` is not going to pose a problem.

However, note that this is not null-terminated.