# Is there a way to initialize an array with a buffer at time of declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11

Basically, I'm trying to do this:

```
char x[] = "hello";
char* y = new char[sizeof(x)](x); // won't work.
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c27af4a654347d7)

Is there a way to do this cleanly?  No comments on DO NOT USE raw arrays, or raw pointers please.

Comment: What do you mean don't use raw arrays or raw pointers? Isn't that what you're asking about?

Comment: If you're using C++11 as your tags suggest, then you can use [std::array in the manner shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27708185/919747).

Comment: [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is the way to do it cleanly.

Comment: @Daniel He is asking us not to do comments like `DO NOT USE raw arrays, or raw pointers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write a function.

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
T* new_array(T const(&arr)[N])
{
    T* p = new T[N];
    std::copy(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), p);
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    char x[] = "hello";
    char* y = new_array(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The C way:

```
char* y = strdup(x);
free(y);
```