# dynamically allocate string literal

Tags: c++, dynamic, dynamic-arrays

I was wondering if it is possible to dynamically allocate a string literal?

I know you are able to do

```
char * letter = new char('b');
```

but is it possible to allocate a string literal like that

For example:

```
char * letter = new char("Hello");
```

Comment: What programming language are you asking this for ?

Comment: You could strncpy your read-only string to a new dynamically allocated stringbuffer?

Comment: Question has been asked before.

 [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27707631/how-to-initialize-the-dynamic-array-of-chars-with-a-string-literal-in-c

Comment: @HoangMinh: It's quite clearly different. This OP is using `new`; the other one is using modern C++ features.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're right. I was so quick to make a judgement. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can and should do is use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) and initialize it from a literal like

```
 std::string mystring{"Hello"};
```

When you do that, `mystring` is allocated on the stack and its content is initialized from `"Hello"` (perhaps by copying it, but read about small string optimization, or short string optimization).

When that string is destroyed (e.g. at the end of the containing block), its storage (and perhaps the internal copy, if one was made) will be released.

If you insist for having a pointer to a heap-allocated C string, you could use `strdup` (then release it with `free`, not `delete`); if you want a raw array of `char`, you could use

```
 char* p = new char[sizeof("Hello")]; // or new char[6]
 strcpy(p,"Hello");
```

but this works only for *literal* strings like `"Hello"` and you should use the *same* literal string `"Hello"` twice (or use `strlen("Hello")+1` instead of `sizeof("Hello")`, which is 6, because of the terminating zero byte).

Notice that in all cases you never dynamically allocate a string literal. A compiler is permitted to (and often does) put the literal string in the read-only [code segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) of the produced binary [executable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). What you can do is allocate in heap a memory zone filled with a *copy* of that literal string (or use a *pointer* `const char* pc = "hello";`)

Answer (score 2):

You can *never* allocate a literal, dynamically or otherwise. Literals are literals; they are baked-in by definition.

You can certainly dynamically allocate a `char` and *initialise it from a literal*, as you've done in your example.

As for your question, though, initialising from string literals is a bit more tricky, because you can only get your own `char[N]` from string literal initialisation using the normal initialisation syntax:

```
char[] str = "hello";  // special rules apply here
```

and it is not possible to initialise a dynamically-allocated array. There's just no way to do it in the `new[]` syntax.

---

You could dynamically allocate a pointer to a string literal:

```
const char** s = new const char*("hello");
```

but that's totally useless.

---

The closest I think you can get is:

```
char* str = new char[5]{'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

---

But, honestly, just use a `std::string` instead:

```
std::string str("hello");
```

It was invented specifically to solve these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
int size = 6;
char * letter = new char[size];

strcpy(letter, "Hello");
std::cout << letter;

delete[] letter;
```

But remember to delete your variable because in this example your variable 'letter' assigned in 'heap'

Comment: Except it's 2015 and we haven't used raw `new[]` and `delete[]` for years. `auto letters(std::make_unique<char[]>(6));` would be better. Or, y'know, `std::string`...

Comment: I know that! question was not about std::string

Comment: Um the question was about dynamically allocating a string. That _is_ `std::string`. What you're doing here is teaching outdated and dangerous methodologies. Irresponsible!

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe that is dangerous but basic methodologies is important in C++!

Comment: `new` and `delete` are not "basic methodologies". They are advanced, expert tools.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good programmers have never used `new[]` and `delete[]`. Even obfuscated in an `auto ... make_unique`.  If for some reason, you cannot use `std::string`, you implement something similar.  (And have since long before C++ got its first standard.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Did you mean to ping Garnik instead?

Comment: @Garnik: That's not true in the slightest.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that sometimes you have no choice to use std::string or C++ 11 so you have to know about new[] and delete[].

Comment: @Garnik: Not only is that wrong, but we are not talking about what you "sometimes" might have to do: we are talking about the technologies you teach to beginners to get them starter.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No.  I actually agree with his statement, "without new and delete, you can't learn C++".  But `new[]` and `delete[]` should never be used.  Whether hidden in a `std::make_unique<Type[]>` or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
string* p=new string {"Dynamically allocated string"};
```

> strings can be dynamically allocated using the above syntax

Answer (score -2):

No it is not because when you are writing

> char * letter = new char("Hello");

you are declaring a pointer to a character string but assigning it a value that is a constant char which is not possible.

Comment: this is not true. this is nonsensical/meaningless, actually.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: `error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'`